# How to tell whether a purchase used an iTunes gift card or my credit card?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I redeemed an iTunes gift card and purchased some songs. When i tried to go see how much money I had left on the card it said: credit card total $1.29. This information was displayed underneath latest purchases in my account information. Does this mean it was charged to the credit card or the gift card?

Comment: If you have any iTunes Credit (Gift Cards) available and enough to complete a purchase, it will be used before your credit card.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a credit card assigned to your account as well as a gift card, **purchases will use the gift card first** as a rule. Only when the gift card is consumed or can not cover the entire cost of the purchase will money be deducted from your credit card.